# Laravel 5. Eloquent relations through several tables and behaviour in foreach

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have the following Models:

**Shop_list:**

```
public function shopListItem()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Shopping_list_item::class, 'shopping_list_id');
}
```

**Shopping_list_item:**

```
public function shoppingList()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
}

public function product()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
}
```

**Product:**

```
public function shopListItem()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Shopping_list_item::class);
}
```

When I execute this code:

```
{{$shoppinglists->shopListItem()->first()}}
```

I get the following correct result:

```
  {"id":1,"shopping_list_id":13,"product_id":69,"quantity":4,"created_at":"2016-09-05 19:23:35","updated_at":"2016-09-05 19:34:53"}
```

But if I want to loop and get id:

```
@foreach($shoppinglists as $sh)
{{$sh->shopListItem()->id}}
@endforeach
```

Then I get the following error:

```
Call to a member function shopListItem() on boolean
```

**Question:** Why in the loop the object is transformed to a boolean? What is the correct way to loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to access the attributes of the related model, you need to use the object, not the function. Note the lack of parenthesis.

```
{{$sh->shopListItem->id}}
```

Since it's a `hasMany` relationship, `shopListItem` would be an array that you'll need to iterate through:

```
@foreach($sh->shopListItem AS $item)
{{ $item->id }} 
@endforeach
```

Comment: Now I get the following error:
**Trying to get property of non-object**

Comment: Thank you! Could you please give some links where I can read about difference of `shopListItem` and `shopListItem()`, so I have better understanding?

Comment: That should be a fine explanation http://laravel-tricks.com/tricks/correctly-using-eloquent-relationships